# Doxygen and add a value of an attribute to the output documentation

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen, servicestack

[ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net) marks rest paths for web services using c# attributes.

For example

```
[RestService("/hello1")]
[RestService("/hello2")]
public class Hello
```

I would like to make Doxygen include values of the RestService attribute in the doxygen output for the Hello class. I'm not concerned too much with pretty formattin if the full line with brackets is included in the output document.

Any suggestions?

A quick and dirty trick would be a preferable to writing a Doxygen extension ;)

Cheers

Tymek

====EDIT

The Python version (so will work on Windows easily) of *doxygen* user's answer would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print "No input file"
else:
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        re1 = re.compile("\[RestService\(\"(.*)\",.*\"(.*)\"\)]")
        re1.search(line)
        sys.stdout.write(re1.sub(r"/** \\b RestService: \2 \1\\n */\n", line))
        #sys.stdout.write(line)
        line = f.readline()
    f.close()
```

and the DOXYFILE would have:

```
INPUT_FILTER           = "doxygenFilter.py"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make an input filter that converts a line with

```
[RestService("/hello1")]
```

to

```
/** \b RestService: "/hello1"\n */
```

like for instance by putting following piece of perl magic in a file called `filter.pl`:

```
open(F, "<", $ARGV[0]);
while(<F>) { /^\s*\[RestService\((.*)\)\]\s*$/ ? 
             print "/** \\b RestService: $1\\n */\n" : print $_; }
```

and use that with the `INPUT_FILTER` tag in the Doxyfile:

```
INPUT_FILTER           = "perl filter.pl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a python or perl scrip, it made more sense to me to do it in C#

As an added bonus **inline** xml documentation for attributes will also be added to the documentation.
Example:

```
[FromForm(Name = "e_mail")]
[Required] /// <div>Specifies that a data field value is required.</div><p>More info...</p>
```

Name the C# console project "AttributesDocumenter" and use the resulting binary with the INPUT_FILTER tag in the Doxyfile:
`INPUT_FILTER           = "AttributesDocumenter.exe"`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AttributesDocumenter
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1)
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("No input file");
                return;
            }

            var f = File.OpenText(args[0]);
            while (!f.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = await f.ReadLineAsync();
                var match = Regex.Match(line, @"\s*\[(.*)]\s*");

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    var inlineXmlComment = Regex.Match(line, @".*\/\/\/");
                    if (inlineXmlComment.Success)
                    {
                        var inlineXmlCommentList = new Regex(@"\s*(</?([^>/]*)/?>).*").Matches(line);
                        var inlineXmlCommentCombined = string.Join("", inlineXmlCommentList);
                        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{inlineXmlComment.Value} <para><b>Attribute:</b> {match.Value}</para> {inlineXmlCommentCombined}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{line} /// <para><b>Attribute:</b> {match.Value}</para>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```