# Doxygen commenting parameters for unmanaged code in c# wrapper

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document our C# wrapper methods. Some of the methods have unmanaged parameters which are visible in the declaration and are written to the documentation e.g.

```
void Register(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] byte nPriority,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] ITag Tag)
```

I would like Doxygen to hide the marshalling part of the declaration in the documentation i.e.

```
void Register(
    byte nPriority,
    ITag Tag)
```

Is this possible with Doxygen or will I have to post-process the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an input filter similar to what is shown here:

[Doxygen and add a value of an attribute to the output documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290340/doxygen-and-add-a-value-of-an-attribute-to-the-output-documentation/9301462#9301462)

Comment: Thanks!  The solution worked - I created a Perl filtering script that covered all the cases for matching marshalled parameters and this is invoked from within doxygen.