# Doxygen annotation/attribute are ignored

Tags: java, c#, annotations, doxygen

I use doxygen to generate xml which then i transform to a custom documentation.

Is there a possibility that doxygen includes the annotation of a field / class / function.

The annotation are ignored in both java and c#.
ex:

```
class User
{ 
    [Required]
    string UserName {get;set;}              
}
```

the "Required" annotation is not parsed/displayed in doxygen.

What I would like to have in the xml / html output of doxygen is all the annotated Annotations of a property / field / class (in the ex. "[Required]").

Answer (score 1):

`EXTRACT_ALL=YES` is useless in this case. Look at this answer, I think it is good idea:
[Doxygen and add a value of an attribute to the output documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290340/doxygen-and-add-a-value-of-an-attribute-to-the-output-documentation)

So you have to create filter (for example in phyton) which will be used by Doxygen to convert annotation to comment. Don’t forget to inform Doxygen about your filter: `INPUT_FILTER = doxygenFilter.py`
I have the same problem so I modified that example in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print "No input file"
else:
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        re1 = re.compile("\s*\[(.*)]\s*")
        re1.search(line)
        sys.stdout.write(re1.sub(r"/// <para>Annotation: [\1]</para>\n", line))
        #sys.stdout.write(line)
        line = f.readline()
    f.close()
```

So code like

```
[AnyAnnotation()]
```

Will be converted to:

```
/// <param> Annotation [AnyAnnotation()] </param>`
```

So I got very nice result. Tag `<param>` is to avoid Doxygen put this annotation description to main description. Instead it will put it to remarks section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking but I will say a few things that might help you.

Doxygen must be configured to produce documentation for code elements that have no Doxygen comments.  In other words, you can tell Doxygen to produce documentation for all functions, variables, macros, etc even if they aren't documented in the code.  Set `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` in your config file.

If you run `DoxyWizard` you will get a better feel for all of the available options and the effect of each option.  `DoxyWizard` is the GUI front end to Doxygen.

And by the way, bravo for documenting your code!

Comment: Thx. for your comment. I already use DoxyWizard to experiment with doxygen :) (but great tip, didn't use it for a while, when I started to work with doxygen.
I edited my question. The problem is, that doxygen does ignore the annotations (in my exapel [Required]). I tired the EXTRACT_ALL = YES